# TestNG property "delegateCommandSystemProperties" in maven surefire

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

TestNG property "delegateCommandSystemProperties" is not working with maven surefire plugin.

I am trying to run a single test in testng.xml which uses parameter named "count"

Eventhough I pass the variable as below

```
mvn test -Dcount=2 -Dtest=<XXXXXX>
```

the error thrown is

> Parameter 'count' is required by @Test on method XXXXXX but has not
>   been marked @Optional or defined

Has anyone tried to use delegateCommandSystemProperties with maven surefire???

pom.xml snippet where I configured the property

```
 <plugin>
         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
         <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
            <properties>
                <property>
                 <name>delegateCommandSystemProperties</name>
                 <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
            :
            :
```

In a nutshell, I need help in passing parameter to testng test from maven surefire command!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delegateCommandSystemProperties is an ant task. In order to pass parameter in commandline from maven surefire following is the way

```
mvn test -DargLine="-Dcount=2"
```